# Reverse IP configuration in a VPS with several registered domains to avoid spam mails

Tags: email, server, cpanel, vps, whm

Hello everyone in the community.

I have a headache that you can't imagine with this topic and I need your help.

I have a VPS server contracted at OVH, where I have access to the WHM and the Cpanel.

I currently have two hosted domains, I have created for each one their account in Cpanel, so each domain has its own configurations: Ftp, Mail etc...

The problem is that the mail that comes out of any of these domains are going directly into SPAM. I've read a lot on the internet, there's talk about configuring the PTR, configuring a reverse IP and so on.

The thing is that I am confused because I have two different domains, with all their different characteristics and the OVH server is one with one IP and already has its reverse IP.

So when I check the CPANEL of each account in the Email Deliverability option it tells me that there is a problem with the PTR.

The truth is that I have no idea how to change this for each domain, each domain appears in the DNS zone of the WHM and I can edit or add what I need but I see that everything is fine.

I don't know what to change or how to change it. I hope you can guide me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your cPanel/WHM server ip address has to have a valid PTR record which should matche your server's hostname. If the PTR doesn't match the hostname then that's a reason your emails go to SPAM. You should also check your server ip address to see if it's listed in any blacklist. You can check that on mxtoolbox.com for example. You also need to have valid DKIM, SPF and DMARC dns records for your domains.